# In Blood Bowl Seaon 1 (or Chaos edition or Blood Bowl 2 if you prefer), is tackle better than tentacles or prehensile tail?

Tags: blood-bowl-legendary-edition, blood-bowl-2

This is technically a board game, but I'm wanting to know this for the video game adaptations of this game. I was thinking of starting to play Chaos edition online, which is based on the season 1 rules. Anything that would apply to season 1 should also apply to legendary edition, chaos edition, and blood bowl 2 though.

I was thinking of playing Chaos, which has free access to premium 'skills' called 'mutations'. Many of them do essentially the game thing as more ordinary skills, but in a different way.

I will have to go a bit into the mechanics to explain what the difference between these three are. They mainly center around dodging. When a player (the name for a unit in the game rather than the actual human player which is called a coach) tries to move away from another player, they must roll a 'dodge check'. If they fail the roll, they get knocked down. The roll is made on a d6, to give you an idea of probability. All the skills I mentioned interact with this mechanic. First off though, is the dodge skill. What this skill does two things. When a player with the dodge skill attempts to dodge, if they fail the check they get to re-roll it once for free. Obviously, this increases the odds of them making it.

Dodge however also applies to blocking (the game's equivalent of combat). To make things simple, the 'block dice' are d6s and 3 of the sides will result in the defender getting knocked down. Dodge however grants immunity to one of these 3 effects, turning it into a push effect.

This is where tackle comes into play. What it does is simply stop the dodge skill from working. If a player with dodge attempts to move away from an opposing player with tackle, they won't get the free re-roll. On top of this, if a player with tackle blocks a player with dodge, the 'defender stumbles' result will apply to them as if they didn't have dodge.

Of course, the problem in comparing it to the other two skills is that tackle only affects players who have dodge. It does absolutely nothing to players who don't have it. Both tentacle and prehensile tail do affect all players however. They work in different ways. Prehensile tail is the simplest, just increasing the difficulty of a dodge check by 1. Tentacles is a bit more complicated. Instead of doing a normal dodge roll, the dodging character rolls 2d6, and adds the difference between their strength and the character with tentacles. If they roll 5 or less, they don't move at all. Though doesn't result in a knock-down though.

So yeah, comparing these is rather hard. Tackle only affects players who have the dodge skill. Prehensile tail affects everyone equally, but the decrease in odds is less than what you would get from tackle. Tentacles doesn't knock down the player if they fail, and forces them to essentially do the check with the strength rather than agility.

Also, characters that this would apply to tend to have different stats than other players. Players who start with the dodge skill tend to have low armor values, making getting knocked down more risky. Also, characters that do tend to dodge often have high agility scores and low strength scores. Coaches tend to prefer to not have players with no dodge skill or a low agility attempt a dodge roll. Such players are normally better off just standing and fighting than attempting to run, though sometimes they may have to anyway since the way to technically win is to score touchdowns. The reason I'm mentioning that is because this adds a whole new layer of complexity.

So, which of these are better? Tackle increases the chance of a knockdown the most but only to specific players, prehensile tail affects everyone equally but doesn't change the odds as much as tackle would against a dodge player, and tentacles works best against low-strength characters, but also prevents a knockdown from happening regardless of the outcome meaning its only useful to keep players from running from you. If you have a choice between all 3, which is the best to choose? Having 2 is technically possible, but each player can only acquire up to 6 skills (ignoring the ones they start with), so that isn't always possible.

If it matters, I was thinking of putting block, pile on, mighty blow, claws, and guard on my players. Obviously, this means I can only choose one of these 3. Unless maybe they're more useful than mighty blow, but I think we should stick to comparing these three skills that essentially try to accomplish the same task but in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided that tackle is better. There is a bit of subjectivity to it. Is it better to do better against a limited number of players, or to do better against all players equally but not as much.

Looking over the units, I think tackle would be more beneficial. None of the players that start with dodge have an armor value above 7. Claw has no effect on players unless their armor is 8+. This means that tackle would affect players that claw does not. Essentially, having both would turn all players into base linemen. Minimal armor, and no dodge. Linemen aren't much of a threat, so doing better against them isn't really necessary. It is of course possible though to give a player with armor 8+ the skill 'dodge' as they level up, but still they're probably always going to be a minority of players with that skill. Due to the existence of tackle, I hear that giving players dodge is rare. You only use it if your players start with it.

As for tentacles, they do the opposite of what I want. I want players to be knocked down when they fail a dodge so they have to do an armor check. Taking tentacles would lower the number of armor rolls overall.

Of course, it could be argued that half the team could have tackle, but the other half prehensile tail. Given that players tend to bunch up to grant assists (and I will have guard too on top of this), perhaps splitting my team into players with tackle and those with prehensile tail could be beneficial. Besides, I was thinking of giving some of them ball-handling skills instead anyway. They're probably not going to be complete uniform.